# My Code does not add registration data into database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store registration data into database but something I cannot quite understand keeps happening, the line below which is in my register.php form is printed out first before the HTML loads

> query($sql) === TRUE) { echo "New record created successfully"; } else { echo "Error: " . $sql . "
>   " . $dbcon->error; } $dbcon->close(); } } ?>

Here is my code and I also would like to check if the email being used is registered, which in that case one should get an error saying 'Email is already registered'

Here is my PHP Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['signup']))
{
    //performing verfication
    $upass = $_POST['upass'];
    $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

    if ($upass == $pass2){

            $fullName=mysqli_escape_string($_POST['fullName']);
            $tphon=mysqli_escape_string($_POST['telephone']);
            $email=mysqli_escape_string($_POST['email']);
            $role=mysqli_escape_string($_POST['role']);
            $upass=mysqli_escape_string($upass);
            $pass2=mysqli_escape_string($pass2);

            $upass = crypt($upass);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (fullname, telephone, email, role, pass)
            VALUES ('$fullName', '$tphon', '$email', '$role', '$upass')";

            if ($dbcon->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $dbcon->error;
            }

            $dbcon->close();

        }
 }   
?>
```

and here is my HTML form:

```
    <form id="wizardForm" action="register.php" method="POST">
   <div class="row m-b-lg">
      <div class="col-md-4 center">
         <div class="login-box">
            <a href="register.php" class="logo-name text-lg text-center">Timewise</a>
            <p class="text-center m-t-md">Enter the following Details to Register</p>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="exampleInputName">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullName" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="Full Name">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group  col-md-12">
            <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telephone" id="telephone" placeholder="Telephone" >
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Enter email" >
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="role">Role</label>
            <input type="radio" name="role" value="N" /> NORMAL <input type="radio" name="role" value="C" /> COMPANY <br/>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="upass" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" >
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword2">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass2" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Confirm Password">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <input type="submit"  name="signup" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
         </div>
         <p class="no-s text-center">2015 &copy; Timewise Errand Services</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Kindly help!!!

Comment: what are you getting right now ??

Comment: what error you are getting ??

Comment: crypt($upass); this needs to be declared as $upass = crypt($upass);

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")` is not the way you use `isset()` and that code will fail immediately.

Comment: because, your PHP's not being parsed and your escape function's failing you once you've installed a webserver / PHP and used it correctly. Edit: *Ain't that right Sam?* - @JayBlanchard ;-) RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php

Comment: @JayBlanchard The how does one use it? I don't have an idea.

Comment: and Lord knows what the HTML form looks like

Comment: *Too true Ralph. Too true.* @Fred-ii-

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != '')` for starters. But @Fred-ii- is right - if you're not running this on a web server no amount of code correction will make this work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Here is the HTML form: ket me add he HTML form on the question

Comment: Edit your post to add any further information. *Do not* dump code in comments.

Comment: file you're loading is what, `.html` or `.php`? is this running off a webserver with PHP installed? local? hosted? if local, how? as `http://localhost/file.xxx` or `c:///file.xxx`? 2 different animals here. and did you close the form? edit does not contain `</form>`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it is register.php form

Comment: [*This was a multi-part question...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699745/my-code-does-not-add-registration-data-into-database#comment59078165_35699745). You answered "one".

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is running on localhost. Oh! Shit i have seen it was running on c:///file.xxx instead of http://localhost/file.xxx

Comment: just as I suspected ^

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you and how do I use the isset()? from a comment above I have been told that I am using it badly

Comment: I'm typing up an answer as we speak...

Comment: ||||||||||||...Waiting

Comment: typing takes time ;-) I don't "drop in code", I explain. it's down there. not much else I can add to it, except to say that make sure your db columns are correct types and lengths etc. best I can do here ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per seen/discussed in comments:

You were running your file as `c:///file.php` as opposed to `http://localhost/file.php`, hence why it was showing you code, rather than parsing it.

Then `mysqli_escape_string()` that function requires a database connection be passed and as the first parameter:

Consult:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php

Your session's conditional statement will give you a false positive:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
```

which is interpreted as "if is set session array does not equal to"...

As opposed to "if the session array is set AND does not equal to"...

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != '')
```

Your edit with the form seems to be missing the closing `</form>` tag, and is unknown if the element for this conditional statement `if(isset($_POST['signup']))` does indeed hold the same name attribute for it.

Plus, the inputs for the following POST arrays, were also not included in your edit for the HTML form:

```
$upass = $_POST['upass'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
```

Check for errors via PHP, since you're already checking with MySQL.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Footnotes:

You should add `exit;` after header, otherwise your code may want to continue to execute.

```
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
```

---

**Passwords**

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

**Important sidenote about column length:**

If and when you do decide to use `password_hash()` or crypt, it is important to note that if your present password column's length is anything lower than 60, it will need to be changed to that (or higher). The manual suggests a length of 255.

You will need to ALTER your column's length and start over with a new hash in order for it to take effect. Otherwise, MySQL will fail silently.

Same thing goes for using the `crypt()` function. The column's length needs to be long enough in order to accommodate the hash.

---

Comment: I have worked on the rest of the problems as per your answer but I dont seem to get an answer on how to use the {mysqli_escape_string()} I have read but I am honestly getting nothing!!! can you atleast help know how it should be?

Comment: @john examples: `$var=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['var']);` - `$var=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $var);` as per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php and do that for all the ones you want to escape.

Comment: Thank you. again @Fred-ii things are finally okay

Answer (score 0):

```
if (password1 == password2){
```

must be

```
if ($upass == $pass2 ){
```

As you don't have such variables in your script. And your INSERT query must be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (fullname, telephone, email, role, pass)
            VALUES ('$fullName', '$tphon', '$email', '$role', '$upass')";
```

assuming that `$upass` is a string.

Comment: Thanks for seeing that i have corrected and edited the question, but the same thing is still happening!

Comment: I have changed that mistake on the '$upass' variable but  its not working.

Comment: It's still not adding my data into the database and I am getting this code: query($sql) === TRUE) { echo "New record created successfully"; } else { echo "Error: " . $sql . "
" . $dbcon->error; } $dbcon->close(); } } ?> . still displaying before the HTML loads